# How to group by month when dateid is formatted as yyyymmdd

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am working in SQL Server Management Studio. I am trying to get my query to group the number of repeat visitors by location by month for the year 2014-2015. I am almost done with the query, but I don't know how to group the result by month. What code should I insert to group it by month? Thanks!

```
SELECT
    loc_id, date_id, 
    COUNT(visit_type) AS RepeatVisit 
FROM 
    visit_fact 
WHERE
    visit_type = 'REPEAT' 
    AND date_id >= 20140101 AND date_id < 20150101
GROUP BY
    loc_id, date_id
```

`dateid` is a `varchar(8)` column.

Comment: If it's a date - why is it stored as a string?? *Always* use the most appropriate datatype - for a date, that's `DATE` (or `DATETIME2(n)` if you need time, too) - but most certainly **not** `varchar`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume dateid is a text type, use `substr()`:

```
Select loc_id, substr(date_id,1,6) as year_month, count(visit_type) as RepeatVisit
FROM visit_fact
where visit_type = 'REPEAT'
and date_id >= 20140101
and date_id < 20150101
group by loc_id, substr(date_id,1,6)
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to mention, the dateid is a varchar. Would that affect your answer?

Comment: @bad varchar is a "text" type - it's OK.